# converting numpy float64 NaN to Postgresql Null

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, precision, nan

I have a dataframe that has float64 data-type including some NaN in it. I am trying to write the dataframe to a PGSQL Database but it fails with the below error:

`invalid input syntax for type double precision`

Been stuck to this error. How can I write the float column (including the NaNs) to posgresql..? I made the corresponding PGSQL column nullable, but that doesn't seem to solve it.

any help will be appreciated. thanks.

***Update:***

I found the problem why the error was coming. It was coming from the COPY_FROM that I was using to write to Database. The method doesn't allowing writing nulls in a Float type column.

Hence, I used successfully:

> df.to_sql()

which takes around 60 times higher time than the COPY_FROM method.

Comment: If you're using psycopg2, it has a 'null' argument you can set in the ```copy_from()``` function (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).  Does setting null='None' do the job ?

Comment: @Clej kudos to you.. nul='None' didn't work but I tried to dump with null='' and it worked like a charm! thanks mate.

Comment: Glad it served !